# iOS custom keyboard with vibration

Tags: ios, keyboard, vibration

I'm working on my first keyboard for iOS 8. However I cannot get it to vibrate on key press. I use Swift language, and execute this on the button press event:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

AudioToolbox.AudioServices is imported on the file.

When I press the button, the keyboard just hangs for a second without doing anything. I cannot feel the vibration and the text change appears after the hang.

When I do execute this function on viewDidLoad method, the vibration works.

Comment: Try dispatching the request to the main queue. I'm not sure how to do that in swift; I'd have to look it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.  Put a button and textfield in a storyboard and connect them to your ViewController.  Click the button, the phone should vibrate.  Enter text, and when you hit the return key, the phone should vibrate.  I tested the code on an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.1 using XCODE 6.1.

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
    }
}
```